# Skipping Lines in Matlab Code

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a Matlab code that strips the header off of a text file and proceeds in the pattern of recording a line and skipping the next three lines.

I have figured out how to strip the header, but do not know how to code so that the program only records lines 1 (after the header is removed) 5,9, 13, etc.

Any recommendations?

Comment: what about reading all of the lines and only recording the lines you want to keep?

Comment: The lines that I want to keep consistently have a value of 1 in the first column. Is there a way for me to read the file and only keep the rows with a value of one in the first column?

Comment: What do you mean "recording a line"? Do you mean writing a new file without the header and the skipped lines?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your data is formatted, so the actual code you use may differ, but this should give you the idea

```
file_lines = {};
fid = fopen(filename);
while 1
    text_line = fgetl(fid);
    %quit reading on an empty line
    if ~ischar(text_line)
        break
    end

    %keep the lines that 1 as the first value (this is what you wanted, right?)
    data_line = str2num(text_line)
    if(data_line(1,1) == 1)
        file_lines{end+1} = data_line;
    end     
end
fclose(fid);
```